# How to change the default file type in the open dialog?

Tags: windows-10, default-settings, file-types

When opening a new file in a program, you get an option to filter by file type in the open dialog. Is there a way to change this to all files (*.*) each time by default?

[image: example here]

Answer (score 1):

No. This behavior is controlled by the individual software applications. There is not a global setting in Windows that overrides the application-specific defaults.

This is one place where keyboard shortcuts come in handy. You can quickly press `Alt+T, a`to navigate to the File Type drop down box then select the "All" item. Yes, a default would be more convenient, but this is not too bad.